# sql temp table join between servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a summary i need to return to the end user application.

It should accept 3 parameters DateType, StartDate, EndDate.

Date Type will determine the date field I use to filter the data.

The way i accomplished this was putting all the IDs of the records for a datetype into a TEMP table and then joining my summary to the list of IDs.

This worked fine when running on the query on the SQL server that houses the data.

However, that is a replicated server, so when I compiled to a stored proc that would be on the server with the rest of the application data, it slowed the query down.  IE 2 seconds vs 50 seconds.

I think the cross join from the temp table that is created on the SQL server then joining to the tables on the replciation server, is causing the slow down.

Are there any methods or techniques that I can use to get around this and build this all in one stored procedure?

If I create 3 stored procedures with their own date range, then they are fast again.  However, this means maintaining multiple stored procs for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you are running a version of SQL Server older than 2012 SP1, one problem is that users who aren't allowed to run [`DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms174384) (which is most users who aren't sysadmins, see the "Permissions" section in the documentation) don't get access to statistics on remote tables. This can severely cripple the optimizer's ability to generate a good execution plan. Upgrading SQL Server or granting more permissions can help there.

If your query involves filtering or joining on a character column, make sure the remote server is flagged in the linked server options as "collation compatible". If this option is off, SQL Server can't assume strings can be compared across the servers and it will start pumping entire tables up and down just to make sure the data ends up where the comparison has to be made.

If the execution plan is as good as it gets and it's still not good enough, one general (lame) technique is to transfer all data locally first (`SELECT * INTO #localtable FROM remote.db.schema.table`), then run the query as a non-distributed query. Obviously, in order for this to work, the remote table cannot be "too big" and in some cases this actually has worse performance, depending on how many rows are involved. But it's always worth considering, because the optimizer does a better job with local tables.

Another approach that avoids pulling tables together across servers is packing up data in parameters to remote stored procedure calls. Entire tables can be passed as `XML` through an `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, since neither `XML` columns nor table-valued parameters are supported in distributed queries. The basic idea is the same: avoid the need for the the optimizer to figure out an efficient distributed query. The best approach greatly depends on your data and your query, obviously.